# Check if a ListView has no data

Tags: reactjs, react-native

After making a REST request, I want to check if the ListView dataSource has received data. My code looks to something like

```
if(this.state.dataSource.length == 0){
      return (
      <Text> No data </Text>
    );
```

I always get an error telling me that this.state.dataSource.length is undefined. You can find a minimal example in this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/S13xT6Z1M).

Comment: You should use `FlatList` by the way. `FlatList` is easier to work with and has better performance; `ListView` will be deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like :

```
if ( this.state.dataSource && this.state.dataSource.length == 0 ) {
   // your code
}
```

Comment: This is not working, you can check it ion the snack, I updated it.

Comment: @j.doe, then first make sure this.state.dataSource is either string or array

Comment: Will you please post the result you are getting inside this.state.dataSource ?

Comment: `alert(JSON.stringify(this.state.dataSource));` As you can see , you are not getting data in array , its json , you need to check it via key value

Answer (score 1):

You want to make sure `this.state.dataSource` has been initialized to an empty array when your component is created. That way, `this.state.dataSource.length === 0` will be true until your data is fetched.

Comment: I checked this and it still not working, I updated the snack